# Getting old cache view when there is PHP errors in controller - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I have a strange problem. I am using Laravel 5.6, When there is a PHP error or Laravel error (`E_NOTICE`, `E_WARNING` etc) in my controller then instead of throwing error, I am seeing the old cached view. And if I change the view data, it still show me the old cached view, but if I fix the error code then my view is getting updated.

So basically as long as there is any PHP error in my logic I am seeing old cached view instead of exception error(which is desirable) but if there is no error, my view is getting updated.

I have set `APP_DEBUG=true` and `APP_ENV=local` in my .env file. My folders have right permission. No `opcache` or `PHP-FPM` is enabled.
I have run all below commands

- `php artisan view:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `composer install`
- `composer dump-autoload`

Nothing seems to be working. I have also cleared my browser cache and I have manually deleted cache files from storage folder, but no luck

**Server Configuartion**

- PHP 7.2
- Apache 2.4
- MySQL 5.7
- CentOS 7.5

**Edit:**

One thing I noticed, If I leave the application untouched for few minutes, and then refresh the page, I can see the errors, that mean PHP is caching the page for some duration

Comment: This is issue with php version none of the above commands will work

Comment: when error occurs, php thinks may be there is working state of code available in cache so it returns that cached code.

Comment: Thanks Afraz. So basically this is due to PHP 7.2 ?

Comment: One thing I just noticed, If I leave the application untouched for few minutes, I can see the error, that mean PHP is caching the page for some duration

Comment: @sanjay yes it is because of php 7.2

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Is there any setting to modify this behavior ? Something in php.ini file ?

Comment: you will have to change php version to 7.1

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior in a server with PHP v.5.6.40. So I don't think is a PHP version issue.